# Organise web portal database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I wanna build a web app which will store a lot of data for each user, so I've got a question, which solution is better:

- create a separate database for each user
- create one big database and in every table add a column with user id
- ?another option?

Thanks!

Comment: How much data is "a lot"? 10kB? 100 MB? 1 TB?

Comment: More than 100MB

Comment: `another option?` understanding [*entities*, *relations*, ER databases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–relationship_model), their [limitations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Limitations) and alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

There is no question that creating a "big" table with a column for the user id is the way to go.  SQL is optimizes to handle data in tables, not to handle zillions of tables.

Here are some reasons why:

- Performance.  Having a separate table for each user means that you will have lots of empty space on data pages.
- Combining data across all users.  Having separate tables means that your queries will be really complicated.
- Maintenance.  Having separate tables means that adding indexes, new columns, and so on is a nightmare.